# Layout is not going to the bottom! It's on the side

Tags: c#, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I create a new Layout, it is appearing on the right side of the screen. I want it to be at the bottom, below my linear layout. Example in the picture.

[LayoutPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9uRw.png)

Comment: Can you post the XML to your layout?

Comment: TBH from the image it appears that the button is not is the same parent layout as the form fields.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Later I will share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve result like following GIF?
[image]

if so, you can add the `android:gravity="bottom"` in the outside `LinearLayout`, here is my layout xml(If you want layout to the bottom-center, you can use `android:gravity="bottom|center"`).

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:gravity="bottom"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"


    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="First Name"
/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Last Name"
/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="UserName"
/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Password"
/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Password"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"            
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Email"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**update**

Do you want to achieve the result like following layout??

[image]

If so, Here is code.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>
```

```
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="First Name"
/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Last Name"
/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="UserName"
/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Password"
/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Password"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"            
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Email"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want my input layout to be at the top and button at the bottom. Both width should be same as the parent layout which is the whe width.

Comment: @RokasStulga  I update my answer, Is that you need?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I needed. Now i will go and see if this works.

Comment: @RokasStulga Ok, watting for you update. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to mark it as answer(click the ✔ at the right-top of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to set the orientation of the parent layout to vertical. It is horizontal by default.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- your inner layouts here -->
</LinearLayout>
```